# Is C25519/Ed25519 "twist secure"?

Tags: elliptic-curves

This recent new curve mentions something that's new to me: twist security.

http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/bada55.html

Are the existing C25519/Ed25519 curves secure against this form of attack?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Yes](http://safecurves.cr.yp.to/twist.html).

There are several different kinds of twist attacks. Curve25519 is safe against all the ones SafeCurves looks at. Specifically, the cost of a combined attack is $2^{124.3}$, which is considered safe.